# Launching chrome adds port forwards

Tags: networking, google-chrome, port-forwarding

I've installed Google Chrome using the google-chrome brew cask, a while ago.

This morning I noticed that I have various ports forwarded on my mack to random places, as show by the lsof command…

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    4820 skylab  109u  IPv4 0x4409242e9a43494f      0t0  TCP 192.168.20.157:52376->104.16.33.193:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    4820 skylab  172u  IPv4 0x4409242e9a5ac55f      0t0  TCP 192.168.20.157:52308->104.16.33.193:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    4820 skylab  173u  IPv4 0x4409242e9a931edf      0t0  TCP 192.168.20.157:52182->a23-63-99-40.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    4820 skylab  200u  IPv4 0x4409242e9a39fc8f      0t0  TCP 192.168.20.157:52226->lhr25s02-in-f98.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've tried disabling all my extensions & also deleted all the Chrome Apps from the only user I am currently logged in as, but the port forwards are still appearing.  I've also removed & re-installed the Chrome cask.

Can anyone advice why theses are here (if legitimate), or how to remove them (if not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's… not a "port forward". That's a regular connection to a website.

- First of all, `lsof` doesn't show "port forwards" – that's something only your *router's* configuration could show. (True, there are tools to retrieve it via UPnP, but lsof is not that.)

  What it shows is just *live connections*, similar to `netstat` except sorted by process. (Technically it shows information of [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) and other kinds of file descriptors that processes can hold; the `-i :80` filters it down to the specific port.)
- Also notice that all four connections use the standard port `http` (80) on the remote end, so they're almost guaranteed to be outgoing connections *to* destination port 80.

  (Not just because it's [much more likely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) than a mysterious incoming connection, but also because an incoming connection would practically never use such a low source port either).

  *(Though, as a side note, the arrow in lsof doesn't mean "client→server", it just means "local→remote". TCP doesn't actually remember which side was the client, so lsof does not know it either.)*
- Finally, all the listed remote endpoints are well-known web servers:

  - `104.16.33.193` is CloudFlare, a CDN provider used by many websites;
  - `a23-63-99-40.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com` is Akamai, likewise;
  - `lhr25s02-in-f98.1e100.net` is Google.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replay, and lovely, thorough response.  Very helpful